# Angular Moment am-time-ago not returning correct time

Tags: angularjs, angular-moment

i have a time_Sent value like this: 1437203995

for some reason it always returns 45 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to forget 3 zeroes additionaly to your number - 1437203995.

`new Date(1437203995000)` - gives correct `Sat Jul 18 2015`